# How can I format Street Address with AMPscript for privacy reasons?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, data-protection-and-privacy

I'm wondering if there is a way to format a street address with AMPscript to remove the street/apartment number?

Currently looks like in email:

```
Palace View, 2-6 Some Rd, East Suburb, KX8 9X, Country
```

Would like it to look like:

```
Palace View, Some Rd, East Suburb, KX8 9X, Country
```

If so, what function should I reference?

Comment: Could you instead do something like `Palace View, East Suburb, KX8 9X, Country` and just completely remove the entire Street info? or do you require to have the street name there? Just because Street name makes it nigh impossible to do

Comment: @Gortonington yes, I do have access to separate City, Country, and Postcode fields. Displaying it as "City, Postcode, Country" might be the easiest option here.

Comment: yeah, you can utilize BuildRowsetFromString() in ampscript, utilizing the `,` as the delimiter then you just do row 1, 3, 4 and 5 to display or similar. This can also be done via SQL Query if you want it done at the data level

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your data extensions. If you hold "2-6" in seperate column - the solution would straight forward => just lookup the "parts" you need.

Any other case I think you should use RegExMatch(1,2,3,[n]) in your code and output the string you've mentioned.

You could pre-process your data using SQL activities and output the data into a new data extension so it would be possible to skip the RegEx part.

Comment: thank you for the guidance. Unfortunately, the number isn't in a separate column. I'll check out RegExMatch. I'm pulling this data in via a Journey Builder Salesforce Data Entry source, so I'm not sure if running a SQL activity will help in this instance.